# MySQL Substring and Mid Parsing Bug

Tags: php, mysql, linux, substring

There is an interesting bug -for me-.

Please follow the query i executed.

everything is normal.

```
mysql> select hex(current_user());
Result : 726F6F74406C6F63616C686F7374
```

everything is normal.

```
mysql> select substring(hex(current_user()),1,15);
Result : 726F6F74406C6F6
```

i added null string to second and third parameter of substring method. everything is normal.

```
mysql> select substring(hex(current_user()),''+1,''+15);
Result : 726F6F74406C6F6
```

when i add null string to firs parameter of substring.. there is return only 726.:S i was expecting same result of my latest query.

```
mysql> select substring(hex(current_user())+'',1,15);
Result : 726

mysql> select substring(hex(current_user())+'',2,15);
Result : 26

mysql> select substring(hex(current_user())+'',3,15);
Result : 6

mysql> select substring(hex(current_user())+'',4,15);
Result : NULL
```

I tested with Mysql 5.0.95 and 5.1.61  and same issue..! i tested same query with mid function instead of substring.. same again.

Any idea ? i was working on some kind of Web Application Firewall rule bypass and i realized to that bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's converting HEX to integer (by taking characters from HEX until the first non-numerical character: 726) when you apply '+' operator. And empty string is converted (to integer: 0) also.

Example:

```
''+1 => 0+1=1
726F6F74406C6F63616C686F7374+'' => 726+0 = 726
```

[concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function should be used for concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using concat if you want reliable results...

```
SELECT hex(current_user()),
    hex(current_user())+'', 
    substring(hex(current_user())+'',1,15),
    concat(hex(current_user()), ''), 
    substring(concat(hex(current_user()), ''),1,15);
```